# Nested fields not returned in Spring Mongo DB query

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following two documents:

```
@Document(collection = "projects")
public class Project {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String slug;

    private List<Component> components;
    private List<Feature> features;
    private List<Text> texts;

    // constructors, getters and setters omitted
}
```

And:

```
public class Text {

    private String key;
    private String defaultText;
    private String comment;

    private String featureUsing;
    private List<String> componentsUsing;

    // constructors, getters and setters omitted

}
```

Basically I have an array of texts inside a project.

Currently this is the only document I have:

```
{
    "_class": "org.aribeiro.i18n.entities.Project",
    "_id": "5a64b8b65aa0334ada6eced6",
    "components": [
        {
            "name": "Find and Ring portal",
            "slug": "find-and-ring-portal"
        }
    ],
    "features": [
        {
            "name": "Find and Ring",
            "slug": "find-and-ring"
        }
    ],
    "name": "Project 2",
    "slug": "project-2",
    "texts": [
        {
            "comment": "This is to show the title",
            "componentsUsing": [
                "find-and-ring-portal"
            ],
            "defaultText": "Find and Ring",
            "featureUsing": "find-and-ring",
            "key": "findringportal.title"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get only the texts part that match the following filter:

```
{'texts.key': 'findringportal.title' }
```

So I configured this query in my TextsRepository:

```
@Query(value = "{'texts.key': ?0 }", fields = "{ 'texts.key' : 1, 'texts.defaultText': 1 }")
Text findByKey(String key);
```

TextsRepository is:

```
public interface TextsRepository extends MongoRepository<Text, String> {

    @Query(value = "{'texts.key': ?0 }", fields = "{ 'texts.key' : 1, 'texts.defaultText': 1 }")
    Text findByKey(String key);

}
```

Problem is that when executing that query I get a null. The only way to get some data is by making it return a `Project` instance and only the fields defined are returned. But isn't there a way to make it marshal to the nested entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of points

*Problem is that when executing that query I get a null.*  --> Ofcourse you will get null because your repository is `TextsRepository`, which will look for collection called `texts` in database which it cannot find.
You have only `projects` collection in database

```
@Document(collection = "projects")
```

Your Query is correct, but you should be executing this against ProjectRepository.

```
public interface ProjectRepository extends MongoRepository<Project, String> {

    @Query(value = "{'texts.key': ?0 }", fields = "{ 'texts.key' : 1, 'texts.defaultText': 1 }")
    Project findByKey(String key);   
}
```

The return type of the query method should be assignable to the managed domain type(in your case Project).

Comment: I thought I didn't end up submitting this question! I quickly learnt it short after posting. Thanks !